# ethjs - call function with multiple parameters

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethjs

In my smart contract i have two functions:

```
function getPawnOfSponsorship(address invitedPerson) public view  returns(uint) {
    return (pawnList[msg.sender][invitedPerson]);}  

function getPawnOfSponsorship(address sponsor, address invitedPerson) public view  returns(uint) {
    return (pawnList[sponsor][invitedPerson]);}
```

I try to call them via ethjs. Calling the first function (with one paramter) works fine, however, calling the second function does not work. Here I get the error:

errorError: [ethjs-abi] while encoding params, types/values mismatch, types length 1 should be 2

This call works (one parameter):

```
    const SimpleStore = eth.contract(HumanStandardTokenABI, SimpleStoreBytecode, {
            from: account
     });



    const simpleStore = SimpleStore.at('0x3143c78f81b814b3ecc55a96b5b24abf233d6cff');
    simpleStore.getPawnOfSponsorship(document.getElementById('addressOfInvitedPerson4').value)
    .catch((error) => {
        alert("error" + error);
    }).then((result)=>{alert('result:' + Object.entries(result));});
```

This call does not work (2 parameters):

```
    const SimpleStore = eth.contract(HumanStandardTokenABI, SimpleStoreBytecode, {
            from: account
     });


                const simpleStore = SimpleStore.at('0x3143c78f81b814b3ecc55a96b5b24abf233d6cff');           simpleStore.getPawnOfSponsorship("0xBd6d361efDf3cf0f84Bd46cF45A5fA33949BCcc5",document.getElementById('addressOfInvitedPerson4').value)             .catch((error) => {
        alert("error" + error);             }).then((result)=>{alert('result:' + Object.entries(result));});
```

The ABI of the contract:

```
[
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "invitationHistory",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "inviatedPerson",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "name": "pawn",
            "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
            "name": "timestamp",
            "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
            "name": "deadline",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "getInvitations",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "address[]"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "sponsor",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "name": "invitedPerson",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "checkDeadline",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "invitedPerson",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "beerDrunkenConfirmationFromSponsor",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "kill",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "confirmationList2",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "invitedPerson",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "invite",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": true,
    "stateMutability": "payable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "InvitationForABeerSmartContract",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "invitedPerson",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "withdrawInvitation",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "confirmationList1",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "sponsor",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "name": "idx",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "getInviatation",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "getSponsors",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "address[]"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "owner",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "sponsor",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "name": "invitedPerson",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "getPawnOfSponsorship",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "sponsor",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "beerDrunkenConfirmationFromInvitedPerson",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "invitedPerson",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "getPawnOfSponsorship",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "invitedPerson",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "checkDeadline",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "feedTheBeerMonster",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": true,
    "stateMutability": "payable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "invitedPerson",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "name": "deadlineInSeconds",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "inviteWithDeadline",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": true,
    "stateMutability": "payable",
    "type": "function"
}
```

]

Comment: Those two functions with the same name aren't in the same contract, are they? Sorry too lazy to check the ABI.

Comment: They are in the same contract!

Comment: try renaming the second